# Math util in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance() is deprecated now, how to get java.lang.Math in freemarker?

Looking for something like ${X / (Math.pow(10, n))} in freemarker

Thanks,
Giby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DefaultObjectWrapper` extends `BeansWrapper`, so it still has the `getStaticModels()` method.

```
// Do this where you initialize FreeMarker. The config variable is assumed
// to hold your `freemarker.template.Configuration` singleton.
// We assume that the objectWrapper was already configured, and that it
// extends BeansWrapper (e.g. DefaultObjectWrapper does).
BeansWrapper objectWrapper = (BeansWrapper) config.getObjectWrapper();
TemplateModel mathStatics = objectWrapper.getStaticModels().get(Math.class.getName());
config.setSharedVariable("Math", mathStatics);
```